# XGBoost python custom objective function

Tags: python, xgboost, custom-function, hessian, hessian-matrix

According to documentation,
http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html
if we want to define custom objective function, it should have signature

```
objective(y_true, y_pred) -> grad, hess
```

where

```
hess: array_like of shape [n_samples]
The value of the second derivative for each sample point
```

But, if we have loss function, depending on N variables, we should have NxN matrix of second derivatives, but our hess's shape is only Nx1. Should we exlude "cross-variable" derivatives? Or what else?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ytsaig/a596feec53d2a024ac69f5ae5a83d8f7 here's a multiclass example that probably answers your question. Yes, they have to be excluded, only d^2F / d^2Ni is relevant, not the crossvariable (d^2F / dNidNj)

Comment: Oh and here is XGBoosts logreg example: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/demo/guide-python/custom_objective.py

Answer (score 1):

I think, the derivative that you have to take is with respect to the score that is returned by the `Booster`. Thus, it results in one value per training example (=sample) leading to a [n_samples] array. The score is what goes into your objective function, i.e. x in `(x-m)**2` in MSE or `1/(1+exp(-x))` in the logistic function.